# How to make MOUSEEVENT.ROLL_OVER both enable on two overlapped Sprite in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have two Sprite and they have a overlapped area. when mouse rolls over that area I want to make these two Sprite both response to the `MOUSEEVENT.ROLL_OVER` event. However, in my case only the upper Sprite will capture the event. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just put those 2 sprites into another sprite and listen to the new sprite like so:

```
var sprite3:Sprite = new Sprite();

sprite3.addChild(sprite1);
sprite3.addChild(sprite2);

addChild(sprite3);

sprite3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOverHandler);
```

Comment: But how can I know whether my mouse has moved into the overlapped area?

Comment: Have a look at the target property of the MouseEvent.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet I have tried the target property. When mouse move into the overlapped area, it is the reference of upper Sprite. However, when mouse moves over the other part of the upper Sprite, the target property is also the reference of upper Sprite.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what is your application supposed to do?